# Can I use GlobalSearch in a for loop to optimize for a parameter range in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

**Introduction**

I have created a model that models the amount of carbon in a tree in Matlab. Now I want to optimize this model, using 6 input parameters, over a temperature range.

So I have 3 matlab files:
1. `Optimization.m` - which is the file in which the optimization code is
2. `LLSfitness.m` - which is the vegetation model that calculated the amount of C in a tree considering the temperature of the environment.
3.`Temperature.m` - with a simple 1x365 array of the average daily temperature

I have built the GlobalSearch code, and it works fine. But everytime I change the temperature I have to do it manually. I would like to automate this and built a loop which changes the temperature. The current code is this:

Optimization.m

```
v = [0.35,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.4,200]; %starting values of parameters
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
LB = [0.01,0.01,0.01,0.1,0.01,0];
UB = [0.9,0.9,0.7,0.7,5,270];
nonlcon = [];

gs = GlobalSearch('Display','iter'); %solver object
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point');  %options
objfun = @LLSfitness;
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',v,'objective',objfun,'lb',LB,'ub',UB,'options',options); %problem structure
[v,fval,eflag,output] = fmincon(problem);
[xming,fming,flagg,outptg,manyminsg] = run(gs,problem);
```

Overly simplified version of LLSfitness.m for dummy purposes

```
function [ LLSoutput ] = LLSfitness( v )

%% Dummy model for optimization loop

%% Input parameters

PCallocation = v(1);
PNallocation = v(2);
LeafCallocation = v(4);
LeafNallocation = v(5);
LT = v(5);
LLS = v(6);

Temperature.m
T = Tstandard + 1; **%All average daily temperatures +1**

%% Model

for day = 1:365
    T(day);

**whole bunch of ODEs**

end

LLSoutput = -TotalbiomassC_(365);
```

I have tried making a loop, adding Temperature.m to Optimization.m, and making it an input parameter for LLSfitness.m but that does not seem to work. Is there an option that I can vary the temperature in a loop with the optimization in it, so that the optimization takes the new temperature in the LLSfitness file, so that I don't have to do it manually?

Cheers, Anne